# Native speaker doesn't follow grammar rules

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

One of my clients who is a native English speaker said to me, "**I need the design a stunning app icon"**

To me, the sentence or phrase should be **"I need the design to be a stunning app icon"**

The question is: Do both sentences express same meaning and is my client's one grammatically incorrect?

Comment: The former sentence is not grammatical (not even in widespread, colloquial forms). Did you encounter it written down or in speech? Is it possible they actually said "I need to design a stunning app icon" or "I need the design.......a stunning app icon!"?

Comment: Yes, was this spoken or written?  If spoken, it's very likely that you simply misunderstood what was said.  If written it was likely a typo.

Comment: Building upon Mike Graham’s reasoning, perhaps it was, *“I need t’ design a stunning app icon.”* where t’ /tə/ might sound like “the” but is really “to”.

Comment: All the above, plus very, very few native speakers speak perfectly grammatically all the time. We all have our quirks and blind-spots.