# Would you like to explain these sentences to me?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

1. I need the design a stunning app icon.
2. I need to design a stunning app icon.
3. I need the design to be a stunning app icon.

Please review those sentences and explain what meanings they express.

I'm so confused, I appreciate your explanation.

Comment: Please, start with a dictionary.  Then, if you're still confused, show us what you found in the dictionary, and exactly where you're getting confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Native speaker doesn't follow grammar rules](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/236580/native-speaker-doesnt-follow-grammar-rules)